# Get information out of Azure AD with curl and accestoken

Tags: curl, http-headers, azure-active-directory, double-quotes

Repost-warning but struggling for hours now with curl (Ubuntu prompt and shell script), Azure Active Directory (AAD), Bearer tokens, passing parameters and quotes I can not figure it out with all the help found yet on the net.

I got an accesToken = { a really long unworkable and frequently needs-to-be-refreshed string }

1) When I execute:

> response=`curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName' --header "Authorization: Bearer { this long string from above }"`

I receive a proper answer, a list of all userPrincipalNames of users I have in AAD.

2) When I execute any of below mentioned commands:

> export authentication="Authorization: Bearer "$accessToken
>
> response=`curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName' --header "'"$authentication"'"`
>
> response=`curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName' --header ""$authentication""`
>
> response=`curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName' --header "$authentication"`
>
> response=`curl --location --request GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName" --header $authentication`

I got a "can not resolve host error" or value like '}date": "2020-03-31T15:26:58"40e8-a128-67f994881632",' ...

3) When I execute this command:

> response=`curl --location --request GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName" --header "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken"`

I receive all information of all users listed in AAD and not only userPrincipalName allthough mentioned in url.

My main and only 2 questions are:

1) what exactly do I wrong regarding quotes and

2) How can I get this userPrincipalName only, without typing this long accesToken in my command?

Thanks in advance for advice and thinking along and kind regards,

Aad Dijksman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) what exactly do I wrong regarding quotes

I test in my site and it works with code as below:

```
export accessToken="eyJoexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
export authentication="Authorization: Bearer "$accessToken
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users' --header "$authentication"
```

The whole command snapshot is as below:

[image]

> 2) How can I get this userPrincipalName only, without typing this long accesToken in my command?

**No, it's impossible**. When you want to access Graph API in Azure AD, you must contain your access token.

Comment: Joey Cai, thanks for the very quick answer. Do I understand it correctly as I say that the curl command sec does work when parameterize the accesstoken but not when between these special quotes ` ` and written into a variable? And do I understand it correctly that it is only possible to get only userPrincipalName when fill in the whole accestoken instead of a parameter?

Comment: The code I provided is set accesstoken as variable.